# Reading multiple line into a record with clojure

Tags: dictionary, clojure, set

I am learning clojure and would like to read a records span multiple line into a set of maps. Actually the contents of the file is a copy and paste from the AWS console on the ami image/snapshot/volume and instance list.

The contents of the generated text file looks like:-

```
Record 1 Field Value 1
Record 1 Field Value 2
Record 1 Field Value 3
Record 2 Field Value 1
Record 2 Field Value 2
Record 2 Field Value 3
```

What I wrote is

```
(defn read-file [file]
    (letfn [(readit [rdr]
        (lazy-seq
            (if-let [ami-name (.readLine rdr) ]
                (cons ami-name (readit rdr ))
                (do (.close rdr) nil))))]
        (filter #(not (clojure.string/blank? %)) (readit (clojure.java.io/reader file)))))
```

It works great and it append everything into a list. But my ultimate goal is to read three similar files into three set of maps and then join them together to create something meaningful, found out obsolete records with set difference. I think I can manage to join the three sets of records based on common key field. The problem is I can't figure out how to read the text file into a set of maps. The format of these three file is similar and looks like this:-

File 1

```
*Field Count (N)*
Field Label 1
Field Label 2
..
Field Label N
Record 1 Field Value 1
Record 1 Field Value 2
Record 1 Field Value N
Record 2 Field Value 1
Record 2 Field Value 2
..
Record 2 Field Value N
```

The result list of maps would looks something like this:-

```
(def instance-list
    #{{Field Label 1: Record 1 Field Value 1 Field Label 2: Record 1 Field Value 2 Record 1 Field Label N: Field Value N}
    {Field Label 1: Record 2 Field Value 1 Field Label 2: Record 2 Field Value 2 Record 2 Field Label N: Field Value N}
    {Field Label 1: Record N Field Value 1 Field Label 2: Record N Field Value 2 Record N Field Label N: Field Value N}})
```

Sample Data as below:-

```
3
Name
Instance id
volume id
My own instance 1
Ins-123456
Vol-234567
*Blank line*
My own instance 2
Ins-123457
Vol-234568
*Blank line*
```

My thinking is to read the first line as field count and then split the lines into two groups, one as header and then remaining as data:-

```
user=> (defn parse-int [s]
  #_=> (Integer. (re-find  #"\d+" s )))

#'user/parse-int
user=> (split-at (parse-int (first (read-file "test.txt"))) (rest (read-file "test.txt")))
```

[("Name" "Instance id" ""volume id") ("My own instance 1" "Ins-123456" "Vol-234567" "My own instance 2" "Ins-123457" "Vol-234568")]

Is there anyway for me to turn these two lists into a set of map?

Can anyone help?

Comment: Is `Field Label 1` a string, i.e. `"Field Label 1"` ?  Do you want `Record 1 Field Value 1` as **one** `String` or **two** `String`s or one map, e.g. `{:Record 1 :Field_Value 1}`  ?

Comment: My previous question is more about all these whitespaces : is this the actual data format you have ? can you post a sample of the right data ?

Comment: Edited the question to provide sample data and to reformat the File skeleton.

Comment: Corrected the question, as I want a sets of maps instead of list of maps so that I can perform set operation like join, union, difference, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building a sequence of records using your initial `readfile()` function. I choose to `keyword`-ise the field names and record ids:

```
(defn record-seq [file]
  (let [data      (read-file file)
        nb-fields (Integer/parseInt (first data))
        fields    (map #(keyword (str/replace % #"\s+" "-"))
                       (take nb-fields (rest data)))
        values    (filter (complement str/blank?)
                          (drop (inc nb-fields) data))
        rec-ids   (map #(keyword (str "rec-" %))
                       (range))]
    (map #(vector %1 (zipmap fields %2))
         rec-ids
         (partition nb-fields values))))

user> (pprint (record-seq "./ami.log"))
([:rec-0
  {:volume-id "Vol-23456",
   :Instance-id "Ins-12345",
   :Name "My own instance 1"}]
 [:rec-1
  {:volume-id "Vol-2345",
   :Instance-id "Ins-123457",
   :Name "My own instance 2"}]
 [:rec-2
  {:volume-id "Vol-9876",
   :Instance-id "Ins-123987",
   :Name "My own instance 3"}])
```

Building a `set` of records is just a matter of

```
(into #{} (map second (record-seq "./ami.log")))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an attempt with just the happy case, making no attempt to check that the file has the expected structure first:

```
(defn read-file [file]
  (with-open[rdr (clojure.java.io/reader file)]
    (let[lines (line-seq rdr)
         num-fields (Long/valueOf (first lines))
         fields (->> lines (drop 1) (take num-fields))
         block-size (inc num-fields)
         records (->> lines
                      (drop block-size) 
                      (partition block-size) 
                      (map (partial zipmap fields)))]
      (into #{} records))))

;;Returns #{{"volume id" "Vol-2345", "Instance id" "Ins-123457", "Name" "My own instance 2"} 
;;          {"volume id" "Vol-23456", "Instance id" "Ins-12345", "Name" "My own instance 1"}}
```

Note the use of `line-seq` to do much the same as your `readit` fn. From the line-seq there's a few basic steps:

1. Get the number of fields.
2. Take that many lines and store them as field names. If desired, you can for instance map `keyword` over them here and change their datatype from just String.
3. Drop the field-specification, then partition the line seq into "blocks" corresponding to individual records. I add 1 in order to take your `*Blank line*`s, but these are not used.
4. Build the maps we want using `zipmap`. This is a pretty useful function that takes a seq of keys and a seq of values and glues them together into a map. We always want to use the same keys (our `fields`), so we can partially apply zipmap with them as argument before we map it over the seqs of values. It won't use a value without a corresponding key, which is how we get rid of the blank lines.
5. Use `into` to collect the maps into a set.

Comment: The solution is very clean and short. While my bad that the no. of blank line is 2 instead of one and this solution will mixed up those blank line as field which will crew up the record created. Anyway, thx very much for your help.